# Is a Drinfeld module over an inseparable extension isogenous to one over a separable extension?

Tags: number-theory, galois-representations

I am reading the paper of Pink and Rutsche about the adelic openness of the image of Galois representations associated to Drinfeld modules, i.e.,

[Pink, Rutsche, Adelic openness for Drinfeld modules in generic characteristic](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X08002424)

In this paper, assume $F$ is a field of transcendental degree one over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$, and let $A$ be the ring of elements that are regular outside a fixed place $\infty$. And let $K/F$ be a finite extension. Now take $\phi: A\to K\{\tau\}$ to be a rank $r$ Drinfeld module of generic characteristic (in particular, the composite $a\mapsto \phi_a'$ from $A\to K$ is the natural embedding of $A$ into $K$.)  Then they proved that the adelic representation

$$
\rho: {\rm Gal}(K^{sep}/K)\to \prod_{\mathfrak{p}\neq \infty} {\rm GL}_r(A_{\mathfrak{p}})
$$
has open image.

On page 887 of this paper, in the "Reduction steps" subsection, part (e), they claim that one can assume there exists a prime place $\mathfrak{p}$ of $F$, such that all places $\mathfrak P$ of $K$ lying above $\mathfrak{p}$ are unramified over it. My confusion is, what if $K/F$ is purely inseparable? In this case, it seems that this assumption cannot be guaranteed. Or, is there any well-known facts that lead to this reduction (for example, can $\phi$ be descended to a separable extension, or $\phi$ is isogenous to one defined over a separable extension?)

Any hint is appreciated.